# Spring 3 with Thymeleaf config issue

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Hello I have the following jars in my build path -

spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-spring3-2.0.13.jar

and my servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><br>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="web.controller" />

    <!-- Enabling Spring MVC configuration through annotations -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--  Mapping Static Resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="*.html" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The error I get on launching is -

*Cannot find class [org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver] for bean with name 'templateResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springMVC-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver*

Am I missing any other library here? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the actual Thymeleaf jar. You included the Spring jar that provides the integration but you missed the actual implementation of it.

Download the jar from here

[thymeleaf download site](http://www.thymeleaf.org/download.html)

Comment: Thanks ... I added thymeleaf-2.0.13.jar to the build path. But got a new error - 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/springMVC-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed

Comment: What is the stack trace? You could be missing another jar, or a myriad of other issues. It could be a version problem as well. Try replacing the thymeleaf-spring3-2.0.13.jar with the thymeleaf-spring3 jars from the thymeleaf site.